# Position:fixed inside the wrap block

Tags: html, css, layout

Say I have an absolutely positioned div inside a normal one.

```
<div id="wrap"> <div id="sidebar"></div> </div>
```

In this case, when I state `top` and `left` for the "sidebar", they are calculated inside of the "wrap", because the latter is `position="relative"`.

However, when I change the "sidebar" to `position="fixed"`, the coordinates are calculated relative to the `<body>`, not the "wrap", which results in "sidebar" jumping out of its parent, even though the coordinates stay the same.

How do I make the "sidebar" to stay inside the "wrap", yet be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, documentation for `position:fixed` property is very clear: *Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the browser window.*

So, coordinates are calculated relative not to the body, but to the window.

*How do I make the "sidebar" to stay inside the "wrap", yet be fixed?*
The question seems strange. Even if 'sidebar' stays inside 'wrap' initially, user can always scroll down: 'wrap' will move to the top of the window (and possible disappear), while 'sidebar' will be in the exact same spot on user's screen.

**edit**
An example of element with 'fixed' position is "Welcome to ..." top bar when you come first time to any stack exchange site (e.g., [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

The idea, as @Nikita implies, is not to use `position: fixed` but instead use `position: absolute`.

For this to work you'll also need to position the parent element, `#wrap` with `position: relative' in order to have the`#sidebar` position relative to to the parent element not the window.

- [JS Bin demo of position: absolute](http://jsbin.com/ivowe3/), note that `#sidebar` is fixed *within* the `#wrap` div, and scrolls with the page.
- [JS Bin demo of position: fixed](http://jsbin.com/ivowe3/3/), note here that `#sidebar` fixed to the view-port, and *remains* fixed as the page scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

Give a `position: absolute` to "siderbar", it should do the trick.

Some info regarding [position relative + position absolute](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).